# Extract nested array from JSONL file

Tags: python, arrays, json, jsonlines

I am extracting extra fields from a JSONL file using json2csv.py (compiled using twarc), and am having trouble extracting some text fields that are held within an array. This is the array, and I want to be able to pull out just the hashtag text.

```
"entities": {
      "hashtags": [
        {
          "text": "NoJusticeNoPeace",
          "indices": [
            65,
            82
          ]
        },
        {
          "text": "justiceforNaledi",
          "indices": [
            83,
            100
          ]
        },
```

I am able to extra other fields that don't have arrays using this code:

```
python json2csv.py tweets_may.jsonl -e full_text retweeted_status.extended_tweet.full_text > testfull_text.csv
```

However, I can't work out how to pull out the array, or elements of it. Individual hashtag text can be identified using the following `retweeted_status.extended_tweet.entities.hashtags.0.text` I've tried using:

```
python json2csv.py tweets_may.jsonl -e all_hashtags retweeted_status.extended_tweet.entities.hashtags.0.text > testhash.csv
```

But this just returns an empty column. Ideally I would like to be able to pull out all occurrences of 'text' within the 'hashtag' array into either a single column or separate columns.

Comment: why you dont `import json` and call the `json.load()` method ?

Answer (score 0):

As Adam already said, you can just use the `json` module to access these kind of files.

For instance, when I have the following in `file.jsonl`:

```
{
    "entities": {
        "hashtags": [
            {
            "text": "NoJusticeNoPeace",
            "indices": [
                65,
                82
            ]
            },
            {
            "text": "justiceforNaledi",
            "indices": [
                83,
                100
            ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

To access the information stored in this file you can do the following:

```py
import json

with open('file.jsonl','r') as file:
    jsonl = json.load(file)
```

This `jsonl` variable is now just a dictionary you can access like you normally would.

```py
hashtags = jsonl['entities']['hashtags']
print(hashtags[0]['text'])
>>> NoJusticeNoPeace
print(hashtags[1]['indices'])
>>> [83, 100]
```

Answer (score 0):

**json module: json encoder and decoder**

> **JSON** (JavaScript Object Notation), specified by RFC 7159 (which
> obsoletes RFC 4627) and by ECMA-404, is a lightweight data interchange
> format inspired by JavaScript object literal syntax (although it is
> not a strict subset of JavaScript 1 )...

I encourge you to review and read more in python documentation [json encoder decoder module](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/json.html?highlight=json%20load#module-json)

folowing my comment, the json module and `json.load()` do all the work for you. just import it and call its API.

if you are on python 3.xx:

```
import json
import pprint
json_file_path="t.json"

json_data = {}

with open(json_file_path,'r') as jp:
    json_data=json.load(jp)
    pprint.pprint(json_data)
    # sinse hashtags is a list (json array) we access its elements like:
    var = json_data['entities']['hashtags'][0]['text']
    print("var is : {}".format(var))
    print("var type is : {}".format(type(var)))
```

**python 3.xx console output of the above code**

```
{'entities': {'hashtags': [{'indices': [65, 82], 'text': 'NoJusticeNoPeace'},
                           {'indices': [83, 100], 'text': 'justiceforNaledi'}]}}
var is : NoJusticeNoPeace
var type is : <class 'str'>
```

on python 2.xx the only change is to omit the parnetheses from the print lines. but there is one major difference between the outputs of the above script.

on python 3 the dictionary items type is `str`. which is ready for use. but in python 2 the dictionary items are of type: `<type 'unicode'>`. so be aware. you need to convert it to `str`, just by doing this: `str(var)`